# User is not a constructor

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

im getting error: `User is not a constructor` when trying to add new document to my database. before I used `mongoose.model` without the `Schema` method and it worked great but I had to add validator and it needs this syntax and since then I can't make it work

CODE:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, index: true, unique: true, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

let User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;


router.post('/', (req, res) => {


    var user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password          
    });

    // save the user
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error in Saving user: ' + err);
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('User Registration succesful');
        // return done(null, userData);
        res.status(200).send({user: user})
    });

});
```

Comment: `var user = new UserSchema ({...})` why you don't use this!!!

Comment: it doesnt work this way

Comment: no they are separated

Comment: the problem was that I imported it like this `var {User} = require('../db/models/UserSchema');` so basically as an object but exported it not as an object. `module.exports = User;`

Comment: `var User = require('../db/models/UserSchema');` It also works by what you had done before... Either you can make change in export or in import...

Comment: yep I could remove the {} from one or add it to the other. Sorry for wasting your time I hate syntax issues. lol

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.Schema` is a constructor, so you need to call it with "new":

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, index: true, unique: true, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I fixed my issue instead of

`module.exports = User;`

I had to do:

`module.exports = {User};`